IP whitelisting with Hyperforce: Can we whitelist AWS region addresses?
When Hyperforce comes in, we won't be able to use IP whitelisting as a security solution for API connections.
As a workaround can we white list all the IP's from the AWS region that will contain our instances in our chosen region post Hyperforce migration?
If not, what alternatives should we consider?  Any help appreciated thanks

Dupe of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/420629/are-we-able-to-whitelist-salesforce-apex-servers-through-domains-ips-are-not
